# Upload a video - getting Null as path

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have used the below code to upload a video. I am using the below code to do this, but I am getting `"cursor"` variable as `NULL`. Can someone please let me know whats wrong in the code below or any other code snippet to upload a video.

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION}; 
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
    int fileSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
    long duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION)));


    //some extra potentially useful data to help with filtering if necessary
    System.out.println("size: " + fileSize);
    System.out.println("path: " + filePath);
    System.out.println("duration: " + duration);

    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Your uri is probably not valid.

Comment: @Merlevede here is the uri: file:///mnt/sdcard/Movies/sample.mov